# enum overloading operator | constexpr and runtime

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a predeclared enum:

```
enum class TheEnum : std::uint32_t;
```

Followed by operator overloading:

```
constexpr TheEnum operator|(TheEnum const a, TheEnum const b)
{
    return TheEnum(std::uint32_t(a) | std::uint32_t(b));
}
```

With the definition:

```
enum class TheEnum : std::uint32_t
{
    A = 1 << 0,
    B = 1 << 1,
    C = 1 << 2,
    D = 1 << 3,
    Val0 = TheEnum::A | TheEnum::C,
    Val1 = TheEnum::A | TheEnum::D,
    Val2 = TheEnum::B | TheEnum::D
};
```

I try to have the operator| constexpr and not constexpr in the same time.
Currently if I add the (not constexpr):

```
inline TheEnum operator|(TheEnum const a, TheEnum const b)
{
    return TheEnum(std::uint32_t(a) | std::uint32_t(b));
}
```

My compiler said it's already defined.
The constexpr allow me to do some typetrait operations, but I need the same operators for runtime evaluation.

Comment: And why do you try to define two identical operators?

Comment: All `constexpr` functions can be used at runtime.

Comment: ([dcl.constexpr], §7.1.5/2 in the C++11 standard): "constexpr functions and constexpr constructors are implicitly inline (7.1.2)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`constexpr` on a function means that the function *may* be evaluated at compile-time. It does not mean that it *has* to be evaluated at compile-time.

You want to declare your function `constexpr` and that is enough for both compile-time and run-time use.

You cannot declare two functions that only differ on `constexpr` and/or `inline`. These specifiers are not part of the function signature and therefore do not determine separate overloads of a function. Whether or not you use them, you are referring to the same entity.

Comment: Thanks, I don't need to have double overload.
[Fixed]